# How can I disable selected attribute from select2() dropdown Jquery?

Tags: attributes, jquery-select2, selected

I know how to enable the selected attribute from dropdown; I can use this code :

```
$('select').select2();
```

but my problem is how to disable it ? thx
[image: Click Here]

Comment: it is a JQuery plugin

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For those using Select2 4.x, you can disable an individual option by doing:

```js
$('select option:selected').prop('disabled', true);
```

For those using Select2 4.x, you can disable the entire dropdown with:

```js
$('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I edited my post, see the image. This method is not working. I think there is a specific function from select2 for this, but Im a newbie to this.

Comment: I tried this version to : $('select option:selected').attr('disabled','true');

Comment: I'm a little confused, you want to disable the select element or an option of the select? If it is the select element try: $('select').select2().enable(false);

Comment: it works for the firs time, but for the second times it disables all of the 2 dropdowns. Can I do something like this?  $(' #subTasks select').select2().enable(false), where id ="subTasks" belongs to the second dropdown

Comment: $('#subTasks').select2().enable(false) => I want to write this, but it disables it completly even if I want to choose another value for Tasks,Subtask it is still disabled. I dont know if you understand me :D

Comment: In that case you have to control the disable/enable action depending on what you select in the in the Task select element. Remember that you can enable the Subtask again by doing this: $('#subTasks').select2().enable(true).

Comment: this answer not work for me, in select2.js it gave me error "throw "query function not defined for Select2 " + opts.element.attr("id");" answer from user4105545 work fine

Comment: As of Select2 4.1, they've removed support for .enable:
'$("select").prop("disabled", true); // instead of $("select").enable(false);'

Comment: Following this : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5309#issuecomment-405140337 I was doing $("select").select2().prop("disabled", false), which is WRONG. You have to enable on field directly : $("select").prop("disabled", false) or your Ajax option grabbing capabilities won't work

Answer (score 60):

The right way for Select2 3.x is:

```
$('select').select2("enable", false)
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 19):

The below code also works fine for Select2 3.x

For Enable Select Box:

```
$('#foo').select2('enable');
```

For Disable Select Box:

```
$('#foo').select2('disable');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DcunN/

Comment: To disable: it's `$('#foo').select2('enable', false);` in my case.

Comment: `$('#foo').select2('disable');`does not work anymore

Answer (score 9):

To disable the complete select2 box, that is no deletion of already selected values and no new insertion, use:

```
$("id-select2").prop("disabled", true);
```

where `id-select2` is the unique id of select2. you can also use any particular class if defined to address the dropdown.

Answer (score 8):

In [selec2 site](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) you can see options. There is "disabled" option for api. You can use like :

```
$('#foo').select2({
    disabled: true
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Select2 4.1, they've removed support for .enable

```
$("select").prop("disabled", true); // instead of $("select").enable(false);
```

From: https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35

Answer (score 3):

As the question seems unclear, I'm sorry if this answer is not directly related to the original intent.

For those using Select2 version 4+ and according to official plugin documentation, `.select2("enable")`is not the way to go anymore for disabling the select box (not a single option of it). It will even be completely removed from version 4.1 onward.

Quoted directy from the documentation (see https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#select2-enable):

> Select2 will respect the disabled property of the underlying select element. In order to enable or disable Select2, you should call `.prop('disabled', true/false)` on the  element. Support for the old methods will be completely removed in Select2 4.1.

So in the previous answer's example, it should be:
`$('select').prop(disabled,true);`

Answer (score 3):

I'm disabling select2 with:

```js
$('select').select2("enable",false);
```

And enabling it with

```js
$('select').select2("enable");
```

Answer (score 3):

As per select2 documentation: [Click Here](https://select2.org/appearance)

If you wants to disable select2 then use this approach:

```
$(".js-example-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you wants to enable a disabled select2 box use this approach:

```
$(".js-example-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').select2('enable',false);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm disable on value:

```
<option disabled="disabled">value</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the values of the dropdown

$('select option:not(selected)').prop('disabled', true);

$('select').prop('disabled', true);